# How to manipulate modal dialog from other thread in WPF?

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I have a Progress dialog with a progress bar. The dialog is running as Modal. But there is a background thread that needs to alter the Value of the Progress Bar. I am using Dispatcher.Invoke to make sure I don't get any Thread conflicts. But that only works if dialog is non-modal. For modal, I guess it blocks the UI thread and Dispatcher.Invoke waits for some free time in UI thread which there will never be any. How do I do that ?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, you CAN use Dispatcher.Invoke with modal. Showing modal blocks only the function who called it, but meanwhile the UI is responsive (except for the owner window which is disabled by the system) and treats jobs that were executed using Invoke.

Comment: @MaMazav I am afraid you misunderstood my question. I am talking in terms of threads not functions or who calls who. I have a modal dialog running in UI thread. But there is another background thread doing work and wants to tell modal to show a different value on progress bar.

Comment: According to my experience, I still think it will work. the UI thread continues treating jobs while a modal window is shown.

Comment: It is not working. I have already tried it.

Comment: Can you copy your code so I/we can understand exactly what you mean and why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This code will create a thread and a window with a progress bar shown modally.

```
System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart ts = new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart((obj) => {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait a second
    ProgressBar p = obj as ProgressBar;
    if (p != null)
    {
        double min = (double)p.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<double>(() => { return p.Minimum; }));
        double max = (double)p.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<double>(() => { return p.Maximum; }));
        for (var val = min; val <= max; val++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            p.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { p.Value = val; }));
        }
    }
});
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(ts);

Window w = new Window();
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
pb.Minimum = 0;
pb.Maximum = 100;
pb.Value = 0;
w.Content = pb;

MessageBox.Show("About to start thread and show dialog");
t.Start(pb);

w.ShowDialog();
MessageBox.Show("Dialog closed");
```

Comment: So I guess what I was missing was progressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke. I was  instead using Dispatcher.Invoke?